# Having trouble refreshing page with jQuery AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, function

I have a page that uses a couple of AJAX calls to get and update data. A user enters a product number in an input box, then clicks a `<button>`, which runs a function that has a jQuery AJAX call to populate a div. See below.

**HTML**

---

```
<form rol="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="sku" id="sku-label">Please enter the SKU below</label>
    <input class="form-control text-center" type="input" id="sku">
    <button class="btn btn-primary col-md-12" type="button" id="bClick" onclick="getSku( $( '#sku' ).val() );">Get SKUs</button>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="badgeNum" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['BADGE_NUMBER']; ?>">
</form>

<div class="col-md-12" id="sku-results"><!--This div gets populated. -->
</div>
```

**jQuery**

---

```
function getSku(sSku) {


  //AJAX call to get SKUs goes here.
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'sku-query.php',
    async: false,
    mimeType: 'json',
    //dataType: 'application/json',
    data: {sku: sSku},
    success: function(data) {
        var disp = "";
        disp += "<div class='col-md-12' id='skuDisplay'>";
        disp += "<div class='col-md-2'><strong>SKU</strong></div>";
        disp += "<div class='col-md-3'><strong>Description</strong></div>";
        disp += "<div class='col-md-2'><strong>Master</strong></div>";
        disp += "<div class='col-md-2'><strong>Daughter</strong></div>";
        disp += "<div class='col-md-2 text-center'><strong>Location</strong></div>";
        disp += "<div class='col-md-1 text-center'><strong>Update</strong></div>";
        disp += "</div>";

        counterp = 0;

        $.each(data, function(i, data) {
            disp += "<div class='col-md-12' id='skuDisplay'>";
            disp += "<div class='col-md-2' id='dSku' >" + data[0] + "</div>";
            disp += "<div class='col-md-3' id='dDesc'>" + data[1] + "</div>";
            disp += "<div class='col-md-2' id='dMast'>" + data[2] + "</div>";
            disp += "<div class='col-md-2 text-center' id='dDaughter'>";
            disp += "<input class='col-md-6 text-center' type='number' value='"+ data[3] + "' id='dChange'>";
            disp += "</div>";
            disp += "<input type='hidden' id='oldQty' value='" + data[3] + "'>";
            disp += "<div class='col-md-2 text-center' id='dLoc'>" + data[4] + "</div>";
            disp += "<div class='col-md-1 text-center'><a class='inv-click' id='" + counterp + "' onclick='updateDaughter(this.id)'  value='" + counterp + "'><i class='fa fa-check-square-o'></i></a></div>";
            disp += "</div>";

            counterp = counterp + 1;
        });

        //Success function if all goes well.
        $( "#sku-results" ).empty();

        $( "#sku-results" ).append( disp );

    },
    error: function() {
        alert('There seems to be an error fetching SKUs.');
    }
  });
}
```

So the above code works fine. In each div that is appended to the page, there is an `<a>` element. The purpose of these divs being added is that each div has an input box where the user can change a value. When the value is changed and the a  element is clicked, another function, with another AJAX call is run. When the second AJAX call in this function is done running, I need to then run the first function AGAIN to update the page with the updated value. See the second function below.

```
function updateDaughter(getId)
{
var master   = $( "#" + getId ).closest("#skuDisplay").children("#dMast").html();
var daughter = $( "#" + getId ).closest("#skuDisplay").children("#dDaughter").children("#dChange").val();
var loc      = $( "#" + getId ).closest("#skuDisplay").children("#dLoc").html();
var oldQty   = $( "#" + getId ).closest("#skuDisplay").children("#oldQty").val();
var emp_id   = $( "#badgeNum" ).val();
var sku      = $( "#" + getId ).closest("#skuDisplay").children("#dSku").html();

var dDate  = new Date();
var dDay   = ("0" + dDate.getDate() ).slice(-2);
var dMonth = ("0" + dDate.getMonth()).slice(-2);
var dYear  = dDate.getFullYear();
var dHour  = ("0" + dDate.getHours()  ).slice(-2);
var dMin   = ("0" + dDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
var dSec   = ("0" + dDate.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

var dFullDate = dYear + "-" + dMonth + "-" + dDay;
var dFullTime = dHour + ":" + dMin   + ":" + dSec;
var dAllDate  = dFullDate + " " + dFullTime;

var move_from = "Adjustment";

//var created   = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
var worktype  = "Reslot";
var qty       = daughter - oldQty;

alert("DATE:" + dAllDate + ". SKU:" + sku + ". MASTER:" + master + ". LOC:" + loc + ". DAUGHTER:" + daughter + ". OLD:" + oldQty + ". EMPID:" + emp_id + ". QTY:" + qty + ". MOVEFROM:" + move_from + ". TYPE:" + worktype);

var workTypeId = "";
if (worktype  = 'Putaway')      {workTypeId = 1;}
if (worktype  = 'RTI')          {workTypeId = 2;}
if (worktype  = 'Replen')       {workTypeId = 3;}
if (worktype  = 'Manual Replen'){workTypeId = 4;}
if (worktype  = 'Reslot')       {workTypeId = 5;}
if (worktype  = '01 Replen')    {workTypeId = 6;}
if (worktype  = '03 Replen')    {workTypeId = 7;}
if (worktype  = '02 Replen')    {workTypeId = 8;}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://a/location/that/works',
    async: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        workTypeID:              workTypeId,
        completedDate:           dAllDate,
        startLocation:           move_from,
        endLocation:             loc,
        quantity:                qty,
        assignedAdministratorID: emp_id,
        createdDate:             dAllDate,
        startedDate:             dAllDate,
        createdAdministratorID:  emp_id,
        sku:                     sku
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.status == 'Success') {                                        
            $('#result').text(data.status);
        } else {                                  
            $('#result').text('Failed on update: ' + data.status + ', ' + data.errorMessage);                                                                 
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        $('#result').text('There might be some problem on the web service. Please contact administrator.');
    }
});
$( "#bClick" ).click();
}
```

**What's the problem?**

The second function works in that it updates the corresponding database with the information that it needs to update it with. The problem is that I cannot get my page to then reload with the updated information. After I change the value and click the `<a>` tag, the page runs the first function again but the old value shows up. The only way I can get the new value to show up is if I click on the button with the same product number again.

Upon reading about this, I came across that AJAX will run its own process apart from the rest of your function. So in my second function, if I am calling my first function again, what looks like is happening is that my first function is being called in my second function before the AJAX call is even done.

**What I tried**

-I figured that I would try adding `async: false` to both of my jQuery AJAX functions, which did not work.

-I tried running my first function in my second function in various places. Inside of the AJAX success parameter, after the AJAX call altogether, etc... This did not work either.

-I tried to patch this by replacing the old value with the new value in the input box manually (`empty()` then `append()`) just to show the user than their changes have "updated", but even this gets overwritten by the old data (which is not even there anymore because of the second AJAX call). The AJAX call is getting "outraced" by the rest of the function, it seems.

-I tried just triggering the button to be "clicked" again inside, and after the second AJAX call by `$( "#bClick" ).click();`. Same thing. Didn't work.

**What I need**

This is what I need to happen:

-The user types a product number (works)

-The user clicks a button (works)

-The button triggers a function that runs an AJAX call to populate the page with info; each row of info has an input box with a number that can be changed, and an `<a>` button that will run another function. (works)

-When the `<a>` button is clicked, another function is run that has another AJAX call that updates a database with information, including the changed value in the input box. (works)

-Inside of the second function, after the AJAX call is run, the first function with the first AJAX call should be run again to update the page with the changed information. (does not work)

Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: A dataType valid is "json". You should add «dataType: "json"».

Comment: Thanks for responding. I changed my `dataType` to "json". This did not solve the issue I am having.

Comment: «dataType: "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object».
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

I understand, but it's a good practice using this parameter in $ajax() requests. However, your issue is related to other thing.

Comment: In runtime your code is rendering many times the same id='skuDisplay'.
This might generate an issue in the code. I'd suggest to check other way to build the divs without repeating ids. 

Check this link: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2